# Bounce animation from 150% to 100% -css

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

i have an image- circle image and I did not manage to animate it as I need

```
<div class="icon>
    <div class="absoulte">count</div>
   <img src="circle_image_src">
</div>
```

How can I do only in css without javascript a bounce animation 
the image should start from 150% and go to 100% and stop there ,

2-  in the animation . when there is a count number i want the circle go to 150% then change the count div absoulte to somethins (free text) and only then return to 100%(I have angular scope variable if its help)

thx for helping

Comment: css can't change div text.

Comment: you can use keyframes&content to change text - fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/eby9fhyg/

Answer (score 0):

To change the scale of the image, try use this keyframe:

```
@keyframes bounce {
    0% {transform: scale(2, 2);}
    100% {transform: scale(1, 1);}
}
```

This could look like this:

```css
.icon {
 background-image: url("http://icons.veryicon.com/ico/System/Icons8%20Metro%20Style/Logos%20Wikipedia.ico");
 position: absolute;
 top: 30%;
 left: 30% ;
 width: 256px;
 height: 256px;
 animation: bounce 2s forwards;
}

@keyframes bounce {
 0% {transform: scale(2, 2);}
 100% {transform: scale(1, 1);}
}
```

```html
<div class="icon"></div>
```

Read more about [CSS3 @keyframes Rule](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp)